# Why are commercial tomato seedling so thick and strong?

Tags: tomatoes, seedlings

Why are commercial tomato seedling so thick, strong and have so many branches? Take this image for example:
[image]

But on the other hand, most of my plants are super tall and very thin, although they have plenty of space, good light and potted in commerically available potting soil.

Any tips and tricks for how to raise thick and strong tomato seedlings? I make them thicker by cutting the main growth, but not all people do that and still have strong plants.

Comment: I start mine from seed here in Ohio during late mid April, under a frosted skylight.  Mine get this thick and healthy.  I do repot once into 4" containers burying the entire stem, after plucking the first set or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you pinch your growing tips out to encourage bushy growth ?. The commercial ones may also be fertilised a lot and possibly even grown under grow lights which would make the stretching very minimal.